# error installing VSTS 2008 SP1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, windows-server-2003

I am installing VSTS 2008 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 R2 32-bit, which has already installed with VSTS 2008 successfully before. I met with the following error (from install log, at almost the end of install progress from progress bar), any ideas what is wrong?

```
(IronSpigot::MsiExternalUiHandler::InstallMessageErrorHandler) Returning IDOK. INSTALLMESSAGE_ERROR [Error 1718。File C:\WINDOWS\Installer\35d33.msp Rejected by digital signature policy]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag says Server 2003 but the question says 2008...

This is apparently a fix for Server 2003.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925336

Comment: I am confused. "tag says Server 2003" you mean?

Comment: The question is tagged with [windows-server-2003] but your question refers to Windows Server 2008 R2 32-bit. Which server are you having the error on?

Comment: My mistake. I mean Windows Server 2003 R2. :-)

Comment: Ah, then this fix should be perfect for you :)